# Model's function returns Undefined variable: role

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this table structure

users

- id
- email
- roles

role

- id
- role

role_user

- id
- role_id
- user_id

And I added a function in the `User` model which will check for Authenticated user's role. But I get it returns this error:

> Undefined variable: role

```
//User.php
public function hasRole($role = null)
{
    $hasRole = false;
    $hasRole = !$this->roles->filter(function($item) {
        return $item->role == $role;
    })->isEmpty();
    return $hasRole;
}
```

So I can use into something like this - maybe inside a filter

```
if(Auth::user()->hasRole('encoder')) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, By default, a function has no access to the variables declared outside of the function.

This variable can not be accessed from that closure

```
public function hasRole($role = null)
{
    $hasRole = false;
    $hasRole = !$this->roles->filter(function($item) {
        return $item->role == $role;
    })->isEmpty();            ^^^^^
    return $hasRole;
}
```

You can use the `use` keyword, which passes one variable to a function:

```
public function hasRole($role = null)
{
    $hasRole = false;
    $hasRole = !$this->roles->filter(function($item) use($role) {
        return $item->role == $role;
    })->isEmpty();
    return $hasRole;
}
```

They is more info about this particular problem on [this blog post](http://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/04/07/php-use-keyword.html)